# jqPlot Filtering option

Tags: jquery, filter, charts, jqplot

I have dashboards full of jqPlot(6 of them), and they work mainly by time stamp or date or locations.

Is there an option on **jqPlot** to let me **filter** by date or location?, some form of **drop down menu** on the top that connect to chart and get data from json feed. and example or a starting link would help lot .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few ways to do this.

First of all jqplot has a datarenderer, which allows you to get data via a function (which could have an ajax call)
http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/data-renderers.html
If you would change the data after the plot has been drawn, you need to call a replot.
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.replot

you can also load all the data, and have a few preset zoom options or something like that.
I've seen examples for it, but I couldn't find one fast.

For the location graphs, I'd try to show/hide different series. I'm sure the option is available in the legend, so I'd try to catch that event.
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-enhancedLegendRenderer-js.html
If you try $('td.jqplot-table-legend:first').click(); in your console on http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/blockPlot.html you'll get the idea

Comment: Thanks i have used some of the obove helps but mainly i have used ajax call to database and i have created a draw function that did that for me..BUT i still keep the previuos chart and draw on top of it. i have tried .empty and .destroy but it doesnt like it ..do you know anything about this?

Comment: I wouldn't know what your 'draw' function does. I suspect it creates a new plot. You could 'update' by totally destoying the old plot and draw something new, but that's not the way to go. You should make an update-function that loads new data, changes options and then calls for a redraw. Without your code it is a bit of a guess where you went wrong...

Comment: Thanks , I have managed to get it working by defining different functions and deleting the previous chart and redrawing it again using the new data.